# React header is defined but not used

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eslint

I'm facing a problem when I run yarn start in the terminal it gives me this warning:

```
compiled with warning 

./src/app.js
Line 3: 'Header' is defined but never used no-unused-vars

search for the keyword to learn more about each warning

to ignore, add //eslint-disable-nest-line to the line before
```

What does it mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is the question? It tells you what the problem is. You defined header, and you are not using it.

Comment: i'm fairly new to react , can you tell me what to do to fix it ?! thank you

Comment: Just remove the import of Header...

Comment: This is just a warning - your app will build and work just fine. If you want to get rid of the warning, just delete line 3 where you define Header

Comment: in `app.js`, on Line 3, you have `Header` defined, probably something like `import Header from...`. Delete that line and the warning will go away. It's telling you you have the `Header` but you're not using it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you defined or imported Header but are not using it anywhere in your file after defining it. To fix it you can do the following:

- Delete or comment out Header where it is defined or imported
- Add `// eslint-disable` next to Header definition or import
- Add `/* eslint-disable */` to the top of the file
- Use Header in your file

Your app is not broken. The warning is just giving you a hint that if you are not using Header, you should remove it.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The warning is because in your `app.js` on Line 3 you define a variable with name `Header` but never use this variable in this file so it is unused.if you don't want this variable just remove it.